# php, phpMyAdmin - dropdown values not inserting into database

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add the values, that I pick from the dropdown menus (see HTML), to a database table.
Yet this is not working out like I planned.
I'm I doing something wrong?
At the moment the columns for the dropdown values are set as INT in the table of the database.

Code below:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8">
    <title>El Gusto - Sigaren toevoegen</title>

</head>
<body>

    <form action="handler.php" method="post">

        <span class="tab"><b>Sensatie in de mond:</b><br>
                <span class="tab"><span class="tab">Lip:
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" name="sensatie_lip_1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" name="sensatie_lip_2">2</option>
                        <option value="3" name="sensatie_lip_3">3</option>
                        <option value="4" name="sensatie_lip_4">4</option>
                    </select><br>

                <span class="tab"><span class="tab">Tong:   
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" name="sensatie_tong_1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" name="sensatie_tong_2">2</option>
                        <option value="3" name="sensatie_tong_3">3</option>
                        <option value="4" name="sensatie_tong_4">4</option>
                    </select><br>

                <span class="tab"><span class="tab">Wangen:
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" name="sensatie_wangen_1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" name="sensatie_wangen_2">2</option>
                        <option value="3" name="sensatie_wangen_3">3</option>
                        <option value="4" name="sensatie_wangen_4">4</option>
                    </select><br>

                <span class="tab"><span class="tab">Keel:                       
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" name="sensatie_keel_1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" name="sensatie_keel_2">2</option>
                        <option value="3" name="sensatie_keel_3">3</option>
                        <option value="4" name="sensatie_keel_4">4</option>
                    </select><br>
            </span><br>

    <b>PRESENTATIE (SIGARENBAND, DOOS, ...)</b>

        <select>
            <option value="1" name="presentatie_1">1</option>
            <option value="2" name="presentatie_2">2</option>
            <option value="3" name="presentatie_3">3</option>
            <option value="4" name="presentatie_4">4</option>
            <option value="5" name="presentatie_5">5</option>
        </select><br>

    <br>

    <b>KWOTERING</b>

        <select>
            <option value="1" name="kwotering_1">1</option>
            <option value="2" name="kwotering_2">2</option>
            <option value="3" name="kwotering_3">3</option>
            <option value="4" name="kwotering_4">4</option>
            <option value="5" name="kwotering_5">5</option>
        </select><br>

    <br>

    <input type='submit' name="Toevoegen" value='Toevoegen'>

    </form> 

</body>
```

**PHP:**

```
//WARM - SENSATIE IN DE MOND (DROPDOWN)
    //LIP
    $sensatie_lip_1 = isset($_POST['sensatie_lip_1']);
    $sensatie_lip_2 = isset($_POST['sensatie_lip_2']);
    $sensatie_lip_3 = isset($_POST['sensatie_lip_3']);
    $sensatie_lip_4 = isset($_POST['sensatie_lip_4']);

    //TONG:
    $sensatie_tong_1 = $_POST['sensatie_tong_1'];
    $sensatie_tong_2 = $_POST['sensatie_tong_2'];
    $sensatie_tong_3 = $_POST['sensatie_tong_3'];
    $sensatie_tong_4 = $_POST['sensatie_tong_4'];

    //WANGEN:
    $sensatie_wangen_1 = $_POST['sensatie_wangen_1'];
    $sensatie_wangen_2 = $_POST['sensatie_wangen_2'];
    $sensatie_wangen_3 = $_POST['sensatie_wangen_3'];
    $sensatie_wangen_4 = $_POST['sensatie_wangen_4'];

    //KEEL:
    $sensatie_keel_1 = $_POST['sensatie_keel_1'];
    $sensatie_keel_2 = $_POST['sensatie_keel_2'];
    $sensatie_keel_3 = $_POST['sensatie_keel_3'];
    $sensatie_keel_4 = $_POST['sensatie_keel_4'];

//PRESENATIE (DROPDOWN)
$presentatie_1 = $_POST['presentatie_1'];
$presentatie_2 = $_POST['presentatie_2'];
$presentatie_3 = $_POST['presentatie_3'];
$presentatie_4 = $_POST['presentatie_4'];
$presentatie_5 = $_POST['presentatie_5'];


//KWOTERING (DROPDOWN)
$kwotering_1 = $_POST['kwotering_1'];
$kwotering_2 = $_POST['kwotering_2'];
$kwotering_3 = $_POST['kwotering_3'];
$kwotering_4 = $_POST['kwotering_4'];
$kwotering_5 = $_POST['kwotering_5'];

//DATABASE
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Couldn't connect to the database!");
mysql_select_db("el_gusto") or die ("Couldn't find db!");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sigaren(sensatie_lip_1, sensatie_lip_2, sensatie_lip_3, sensatie_lip_4, sensatie_tong_1, sensatie_tong_2, sensatie_tong_3, sensatie_tong_4, sensatie_wangen_1, sensatie_wangen_2, sensatie_wangen_3, sensatie_wangen_4, sensatie_keel_1, sensatie_keel_2, sensatie_keel_3, sensatie_keel_4, presentatie_1, presentatie_2, presentatie_3, presentatie_4, presentatie_5, kwotering_1, kwotering_2, kwotering_3, kwotering_4, kwotering_5) VALUES
('$sensatie_lip_1',
'$sensatie_lip_2',
'$sensatie_lip_3',
'$sensatie_lip_4',
'$sensatie_tong_1',
'$sensatie_tong_2',
'$sensatie_tong_3',
'$sensatie_tong_1',
'$sensatie_wangen_1',
'$sensatie_wangen_2',
'$sensatie_wangen_3',
'$sensatie_wangen_4',
'$sensatie_keel_1',
'$sensatie_keel_2',
'$sensatie_keel_3',
'$sensatie_keel_4',
'$presentatie_1',
'$presentatie_2',
'$presentatie_3',
'$presentatie_4',
'$presentatie_5',
'$kwotering_1',
'$kwotering_2',
'$kwotering_3',
'$kwotering_4',
'$kwotering_5')");

if($query) {
    echo "Toevoeging gelukt!";  
}
else{
    echo mysql_error(); 
}   

?>
```

Comment: Don't you have more information for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<select name="sensatie_lip">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**PHP:**

```
$sensatie_lip = $_POST['sensatie_lip']; // you will get your selected value
```

Comment: Correct!, I just figured that out myself but still thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving name to option tag give name to select tag.
Currently you are not getting the values of dropdown after submitting the form

Comment: Don't understand, you are saying the same thing twice?
don't give name to tag = give name to tag?

Comment: Well now it makes sense.. the post has been edited. :p

Answer (score 0):

Rightly said by Disha and Jasbir,Select way used is incorrect and try changing it as suggested and see that to work

```
 <select name="sensatie" >
                    <option value="1">sensatie_wangen_1</option>
                    <option value="2">sensatie_wangen_2</option>
 </select>
```

So it will display 2 drop down as sesatie_wangen_1, 2 and on save db will have value 1, or 2. It is a hint and you need to adjust code to make it work based on this